# Using passport and passing an error message when user or password is incorrect

Tags: passport-local, passport.js

I looked at the documentation and I'm not getting any coding errors, but I am also not getting the message back. All I am getting is unauthorized in the response if I put in the wrong email and password.
[Here is a image of the response](https://gyazo.com/cf438d8de7da59648360ce8f9fdbce1e)

Here is the code:

```
const passport = require('passport');
const User = require('../models/user');
const config = require('../config');
const JwtStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy;
const ExtractJwt = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt;
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local');

//creat local Strategy
const localOptions = {usernameField: 'email'}
const localLogin = new LocalStrategy(localOptions, function(email, password, done) {
  User.findOne({email: email}, function(err, user) {
    if(err) {return done(err);}
    if(!user) {
      return done(null, false, {message: 'Incorrect email'});
    }

    //compare passwords - is `password` equal to user.password?
    user.comparePassword(password, function(err, isMatch) {
      if(err) {return done(err);}
      if(!isMatch) {
        return done(null, false, {message: 'Incorrect password'});
      }
      return done(null, user);
    });
  });
});
//Setup options for JWT Strategy
const jwtOptions = {
  jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromHeader('authorization'),
  secretOrKey: config.secret
};

 //Create JWT Strategy
const jwtLogin = new JwtStrategy(jwtOptions, function(payload, done) {
  //See if the user ID in the payload exists in our database
  // if it does, call 'done' with that user, otherwise
  // call done without a user object
  User.findById(payload.sub, function(err, user) {
    if (err) { return done(err, false); }

    if (user) {
      done(null, user);
    } else {
      done(null, false);
    }
  });
});
 //Tell passport to use this Strategy
 passport.use(jwtLogin);
 passport.use(localLogin);
```

Comment: Your linked image only shows the headers. Is the response tab empty?

Comment: The response just says unauthorized.

Answer (score 0):

You must be remove line from `route.js`

```
authRoutes.post('/login', requireLogin, AuthenticationController.login);
```

to

```
authRoutes.post('/login', AuthenticationController.login);
```

and also add below code in your controller.

```
var employeeEmail = req.body.username;
var employeePassword = req.body.password;

User.findOne({ username: employeeEmail }, function(err, employee)
{

if (err) { return next(err); } 

if (!employee) { return res.status(401).json("Incorrect email or password1"); }

employee.comparePassword(employeePassword, function(err, isMatch) {

if (err) { return next(err); } 

if (!isMatch) { return res.status(401).json("Incorrect email or password"); }
    return res.status(200).json(employee);
});
```